# Upgrading from ui-router legacy to 1.0.18, causes unknow error. How to fix or debug?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm upgrading from pre 1.x to 1.0.18 and i'm getting the following error

> Transition Rejection($id: 5 type: 5, message: The transition was
>   ignored, detail: "undefined")

When using `$location.path()` to change the `URI` or when using `$state.go('statename')`, and the `statename` is actually the current state. The current state i can fix. But how can i debug, why the `$location.path()` causes the error. The strange thing is, on initial load, it does load all states.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently `$location.path` causes two 'state changes'. This results in the error Transition rejection, the transition was ignored.

As a solution we're only catching transition errors 4 (Transition invalid) and 6 (Unknown transition error).